# EWS not listing inline images among attachments

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, mimekit

I'm *using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll* to read signed emails from an Exchange Server. Returned object's property `Attachments` contains either regular attachments or inline images from the email body.

In case the email has both (regular attachments, body with inline images), only **regular attachments are listed in the `Attachments`. Inline images are completely missing**.

Any idea on how to retrieve both, regular attachments as well as inline images in the body? `Body` property of the email has just the text part and no mention/reference there should be some images at all.

Comment: What does this have to do with MimeKit? I'm confused.

Comment: Later on, I change the message to Mimekit object and read those signed attachments. I've put the tag in there cuz I've seem many people working with EWS using Mimekit, so I thought they might have some insights. Should I remove the tag?

Comment: I am experience the very same probleme here. Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: @Tunguska I don't remember anymore, I think I found a solution but not sure :D If you remind me on Monday, I'll be at work and can check it out for your

Comment: @DurkoMatko That would be great, thanks! :)